# How to detect X motion using Accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

How to detect that phone was moved f.e. 10 meters in 2s using Accelerometer? I need to track when motion starts to switch on GPS.

```
    @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            float accel = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
            g = g * 0.9f + accel * 0.1f;

            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - mSensorTimestamp) < 2000) return;

             //What I have to do here?

            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken, the accelerometer does not work this way, like a position tracker. 
Check [The motion docs on d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel) to see what I mean.

From the docs:

> Accelerometers use the standard sensor coordinate system. In practice,
>   this means that the following conditions apply when a device is laying
>   flat on a table in its natural orientation:
>
> If you push the device on the left side (so it moves to the right),
>   the x acceleration value is positive. If you push the device on the
>   bottom (so it moves away from you), the y acceleration value is
>   positive. If you push the device toward the sky with an acceleration
>   of A m/s2, the z acceleration value is equal to A + 9.81, which
>   corresponds to the acceleration of the device (+A m/s2) minus the
>   force of gravity (-9.81 m/s2). The stationary device will have an
>   acceleration value of +9.81, which corresponds to the acceleration of
>   the device (0 m/s2 minus the force of gravity, which is -9.81 m/s2).

So, I'd recommend you to use the [Location Service](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) directly !

Hope it helps!